# To split hex file by dclfdd or split?

Tags: sed, split

I am solving the challenge about splitting with simultaneous progress monitoring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31021731/54964).
Assume the detectable field of the header is `FA FA FA FA` in Hex.

Steps in splitting by the field

- binary to binary ascii of the data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31026541/54964)
- bin2hex
- mark split points by `gsed 's/FA FA FA FA/\0/100g'`
- split where marks `\0` by pseudocode `split -p'\0' input.txt` which is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211803/16920)

How can you do the conversion bin2hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't access the link you shared...

But, you can use `bc` (bash calculator) utility for the conversions... Maybe there will be a better approach (which i am unaware of :-))

**For hex to binary:**

```
v=F; echo "ibase=16;obase=2;$(echo $v)" | bc
```

This will convert `0xF` to `1111b`.

`ibase` is the input base system (`16 => hex`). `obase` is the output base system (`2 => binary`).

**For binary to hex:**

```
v=1111; echo "ibase=2;obase=10000;$(echo $v)" | bc
```

This will convert `1111b` to `0xF`.

`ibase` is the input base system (`2 => binary`). `obase` is the output base system (`10000 => hex` (`obase` should be mentioned using `ibase` as the base system, our `obase`, `10000b = 16 decimal => hex`)).

Comment: check the output of $(echo `sed '1q;d' /Users/masi/Dropbox/123/r3.raw`)... it should be a binary value... as u r trying to convert from binary to hex...

Comment: How efficient such conversion can be? You go from defining a variable, to echoing and to bc, which is calling the shell each time, taking probably much resources. I put a better focus in the following thread for a single tool in doing this task http://stackoverflow.com/q/31026541/54964