# To use a single command in converting from binary to ascii hex

Tags: sed, hexdump

I am converting binary data into hex and viewing this hex data in head from a continuous stream. 
I run the following where the conversion is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025040/54964)

```
echo "ibase=2;obase=10000;$(echo `sed '1q;d' /Users/masi/Dropbox/123/r3.raw`)" \ 
                                                                               \ 
| bc                                                                           \
                                                                               \  
| head
```

and I get

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: H
```

so wrong datatype.

How can you do the conversion form binary to binary ascii by a single command efficietly?

Comment: $(echo `sed '1q;d' /Users/masi/Dropbox/123/r3.raw`) should be returning a binary value for your full command to give any sensible output... u must get this command fixed first before any attempted conversion...

Comment: @A.M.D No. I think I should be getting hex data. I am converting data from binary into hex and viewing it in less.

Comment: Sorry, unrelated comment here in the body so deleted it.

Comment: If u r looking to convert from hex to binary, ibase=16;obase=2 should be used... but your sed output is not hex either.. i see all sorts of alphabets in there.. fix ur sed command first... then change ibase and obase as required for conversion...

Comment: @A.M.D No. Binary to hex first.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here is that `bc` with `ibase=2` expects the input to be ascii-formatted binary numbers, not raw binary data. Are you perhaps looking for something along the lines of the `hd` or `hexdump` tool?

Comment: @Wintermute Your comment is the solution. I need to convert the binary data first to ascii-formatted binary. How can you do that?

Comment: That rather depends on what you consider to be a line in the binary file -- lines are usually a text file thing. Wildly guessing: for example, `hexdump -e '/4 "%08x\n"' r3.raw` would give you a 4-byte dword printed in hexadecimal on each line.

Comment: @Wintermute Your command gives me like as an output `3e0ab60a
8c0a6d0a
3c0aa50a
980a5c0a
280aad0a
b20a870a
520a9a0a`. So 4 bytes (8 characters in each thing).

Comment: Yes, that's the 4-byte double words in hexadecimal notation. It was a wild guess; I can't tell from the question what output you want.

Comment: @Wintermute I have headers in my data separated by FAFAFAFA so I need to split events such that 100 events in one file etc. This thread is a part of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/31021731/54964

Comment: @Wintermute Make your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Wintermute I  am trying to use your hexdump command for less here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31027735/54964. Just dump everything to less but let the user to read current dump and continuously dumping more and more.

Comment: @shellter I do not want tail because it is too slow in this application. Sed must be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the following code based on Wintermute's comment

```
hexdump -e '/4 "%08x\n"' r3.raw
```

For instance, `head r3.raw | hexdump -e '/4 "%08x\n"` gives

```
ffffffff
555eea57
...
```