# Read hex data into less

Tags: hex, hexdump, less-unix

I want to give a big data file to `less -s -M +Gg` such that read current given data in `less -s -M +Gg`.

### While-loop example (see ntc2's answer)

Less command explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871578/54964). 
Replacing the `yes` by a binary file which is converted to binary ascii and hex:

```
while read -u 10 p || [[ -n $p ]]; do
    hexdump -e '/4 "%08x\n"' {$p}                       \
                                                        \
    | less -s -M +Gg
done 10</Users/masi/Dropbox/7-8\:2015/r3.raw
```

where the looping is based on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/54964).

How can you read such data into less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the details of the example, but I think you want to put the `less` outside of the loop, like this:

```
while read -u 10 p || [[ -n $p ]]; do
    hexdump -e '/4 "%08x\n"' {$p}
done 10</Users/masi/Dropbox/7-8\:2015/r3.raw | less -s -M +Gg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to accept it and simplify the case even further here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31048739/54964